# How to sign out of soundcloud API

Tags: javascript, html, api, soundcloud

I'm using the soundcloud api to sign a user in on my webpage using the client-side `SC.Connect();` with the `redirect_uri`. 
Is there a way to sign out a user as well? Like `SC.Disconnect();` or something?

I use jStorage to store the user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could clear local storage in order to sign the user out – the oauth token is stored there.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking how to accomplish what's been asked (the accepted answer is incorrect).

Call SC.initialize({oauth_token: null}) and that will erase the oauth token, which is kept in the in-memory config variable, NOT in the Web Storage.

UPDATE: There is no way to do accomplish what's been asked, because SC.initialize won't set a value into a field if the value is falsy.